# Error when checking model input: expected conv2d_175_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (0, 1)

Tags: python, keras

I want to train a deep network starting with the following layer:

```
def cnn_model():
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=(3,48, 48),
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
return model

model = cnn_model()
# let's train the model using SGD + momentum (how original).
lr = 0.01
sgd = SGD(lr=lr, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer=sgd,
          metrics=['accuracy'])


def lr_schedule(epoch):
    return lr*(0.1**int(epoch/10))
```

with the following generator:

```
model = cnn_model()

# let's train the model using SGD + momentum
lr = 0.01
sgd = SGD(lr=lr, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
def lr_schedule(epoch):
    return lr * (0.1 ** int(epoch / 10))

batch_size = 32
epochs = 30

model.fit(X, Y,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split=0.2,
          callbacks=[LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule),
                     ModelCheckpoint('model.h5', save_best_only=True)]
          )
```

(validation generator looks similar).

During training, I get the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_175_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (0, 1)
```

I got the following output after typing `print(model.summary())`

```
    _________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_175 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 48, 48)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_176 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 46, 46)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_85 (MaxPooling (None, 32, 23, 23)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_103 (Dropout)        (None, 32, 23, 23)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_177 (Conv2D)          (None, 64, 23, 23)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_178 (Conv2D)          (None, 64, 21, 21)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_86 (MaxPooling (None, 64, 10, 10)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_104 (Dropout)        (None, 64, 10, 10)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_179 (Conv2D)          (None, 128, 10, 10)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_180 (Conv2D)          (None, 128, 8, 8)         147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_87 (MaxPooling (None, 128, 4, 4)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_105 (Dropout)        (None, 128, 4, 4)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_28 (Flatten)         (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_43 (Dense)             (None, 512)               1049088   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_106 (Dropout)        (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_44 (Dense)             (None, 43)                22059     
=================================================================
Total params: 1,358,155
Trainable params: 1,358,155
Non-trainable params: 0
```

What i have tried? 
I was reading this document about "Convolution2D"/"Input shape" https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/, so i tried to change the input_shape, i understand that my output should be 4D but i don't know how to do that. 
Please share if you can help.

Thank you

Comment: please post an output of `print(model.summary())` after building the model

Comment: There's no need to add tensorflow tag here.

Comment: @MaxU 
conv2d_175 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 48, 48)        896

Comment: @assamalzookery, please post the whole output directly in the question

Comment: Check your `X.shape` and compare against your model input shape, first layer in `model.summary`, you should the spot the problem.

Comment: @assamalzookery, as nuric has already said the shape of your `X` doesn't match the one expected by the model

Comment: So how can i change the x shape to match the model shape? @MaxU

Comment: @assamalzookery, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, including a small sample data set](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MaxU Please check the complete code here https://github.com/aalzooke/Traffic-Sign-Classification-

Comment: You need to provide more information about your input. Generally you can use `reshape` to get your input into correct shape, but I think this wont work for you. Your error comes not from your model, it seems you have some error when preparing your `X`. As said above you need to provide more information about this to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nuric mentioned the problem is with input image dimension.

If you input image has a  height of 48, width of 48 and input channel is 3 which results in (3,48,48), then your input to the model be (batch size, 3, 48, 48).

here batch size is nothing but number of training images in a single batch given to model for training

Pseudo code

```
training_list = []
for i in range(0, batch_size):
    image = read_image(training_set[i])
    training_list.append(image)
training_set = numpy.array(training_list)
```

so now the dimension of training set are (batch size, 3, 48, 48)